# interpolating 2D data with data.table - filling NAs

Tags: r, data.table, interpolation

I have two datasets, with timesteps t and height h, which I merged.

```
dataset_a <- data.table(t=rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), each=5),
                        h=rep(c(1:5)),
                        v=c(1:(5*9)))
```

one has measurement gaps, and values where we actually measured, but measured nothing.

```
dataset_b <- data.table(t=rep(c(1,2,4,5,6,8,9), each=5),
                        h=rep(c(1:5)),
                        w=c(1:(5*7)))

dataset_b$w[12:20] <-0
```

merging:

```
dataset_merged <- merge(dataset_a, dataset_b, all=TRUE, by = c('t', 'h'))
```

Now I want to fill the gaps. How do I tell the data.table to use the neighboring values to fill the pixel?

```
dataset_merged[is.na(w), 
               w:= mean(c(the value at this h one timestep earlier, the value at this h one timestep later))]
```

Thanks a lot!

**Edit**
After Bens very helpfull comment I had to adjust the reproducible example: 
His solution works, but not if 'framing' data is missing:
if

```
dataset_b <- data.table(t=rep(c(2,4,5,6,8,9), each=5),
                        h=rep(c(1:5)),
                        w=c(1:(5*6)))
#removed the first timestep in this case
dataset_merged <- merge(dataset_a, dataset_b, all=TRUE, by = c('t', 'h'))
```

```
library(zoo)
dataset_merged[order(h,t)][, w := na.approx(w)]
```

yields

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dataset_merged[order(h, t)], , `:=`(w, na.approx(w))) : 
  Supplied 44 items to be assigned to 45 items of column 'w'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

It would be ok to keep those as NA, but how do I make this clear to the function? 
Unfortunately the original data is not on a regular grid.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks a lot. It seems like this easy solution does the job for this small sample. I will have the actual data running over night. But i am very hopeful. 
If you post it as an answer i can mark it as correct.

Comment: Maybe you can help me out and explain how na.approx treats a case with several NAs? when using your solution for my data I get  ```Error in `[.data.table`(dataset[order(height, datetime)], , `:=`(ze, na.approx(ze))) : Supplied 16885434 items to be assigned to 16888965 items of column 'ze'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code. ``` Since the input is the same value as the output I do not understand where this discrepancy may come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try this approach. Order the data table by `h` before interpolation, and make `w` numeric for decimal. Use `approx` (base R) and group `by = h`.

```
dataset_merged[order(h,t)][, w:= as.numeric(w)][, w := approx(.I, w, .I)$y, by = h]
```

**Output**

```
    t h  v    w
 1: 1 1  1   NA
 2: 2 1  6  1.0
 3: 3 1 11  3.5
 4: 4 1 16  6.0
 5: 5 1 21 11.0
 6: 6 1 26 16.0
 7: 7 1 31 18.5
 8: 8 1 36 21.0
 9: 9 1 41 26.0
10: 1 2  2   NA
11: 2 2  7  2.0
12: 3 2 12  4.5
13: 4 2 17  7.0
14: 5 2 22 12.0
15: 6 2 27 17.0
16: 7 2 32 19.5
17: 8 2 37 22.0
18: 9 2 42 27.0
19: 1 3  3   NA
20: 2 3  8  3.0
21: 3 3 13  5.5
22: 4 3 18  8.0
23: 5 3 23 13.0
24: 6 3 28 18.0
25: 7 3 33 20.5
26: 8 3 38 23.0
27: 9 3 43 28.0
28: 1 4  4   NA
29: 2 4  9  4.0
30: 3 4 14  6.5
31: 4 4 19  9.0
32: 5 4 24 14.0
33: 6 4 29 19.0
34: 7 4 34 21.5
35: 8 4 39 24.0
36: 9 4 44 29.0
37: 1 5  5   NA
38: 2 5 10  5.0
39: 3 5 15  7.5
40: 4 5 20 10.0
41: 5 5 25 15.0
42: 6 5 30 20.0
43: 7 5 35 22.5
44: 8 5 40 25.0
45: 9 5 45 30.0
    t h  v    w
```

**Additional (per OP): If there is a group with only `NA` values for `w` it has to be excluded.**

**Edit (5/28/20)**: To prevent using `approx` when there are less than 2 values available for interpolation, you can also try:

```
dataset_merged[order(h,t)
  ][, w:= as.numeric(w)
    ][, w := if(length(na.omit(w)) < 2) w else approx(.I, w, .I)$y, by = h]
```

Test case:

```
dataset_b <- data.table(t=rep(c(2,4,5,6,8,9), each=5),
                        h=1:5,
                        w=1:30)

dataset_b$w[c(F,F,T,F,F)] <- NA

dataset_merged <- merge(dataset_a, dataset_b, all=TRUE, by = c('t', 'h'))
```

**Output**

```
    t h  v    w
 1: 1 1  1   NA
 2: 2 1  6  1.0
 3: 3 1 11  3.5
 4: 4 1 16  6.0
 5: 5 1 21 11.0
 6: 6 1 26 16.0
 7: 7 1 31 18.5
 8: 8 1 36 21.0
 9: 9 1 41 26.0
10: 1 2  2   NA
11: 2 2  7  2.0
12: 3 2 12  4.5
13: 4 2 17  7.0
14: 5 2 22 12.0
15: 6 2 27 17.0
16: 7 2 32 19.5
17: 8 2 37 22.0
18: 9 2 42 27.0
19: 1 3  3   NA
20: 2 3  8   NA
21: 3 3 13   NA
22: 4 3 18   NA
23: 5 3 23   NA
24: 6 3 28   NA
25: 7 3 33   NA
26: 8 3 38   NA
27: 9 3 43   NA
28: 1 4  4   NA
29: 2 4  9  4.0
30: 3 4 14  6.5
31: 4 4 19  9.0
32: 5 4 24 14.0
33: 6 4 29 19.0
34: 7 4 34 21.5
35: 8 4 39 24.0
36: 9 4 44 29.0
37: 1 5  5   NA
38: 2 5 10  5.0
39: 3 5 15  7.5
40: 4 5 20 10.0
41: 5 5 25 15.0
42: 6 5 30 20.0
43: 7 5 35 22.5
44: 8 5 40 25.0
45: 9 5 45 30.0
    t h  v    w
```

Comment: Hi Ben, I tried to implement your solution to my data, but it didn't work. I havn't worked with approx before. where does the ```$y``` come from, and I havn't seen the ```.I``` notation before. Can you elaborate on this so maybe I can understand where I went wrong?

Comment: Sorry to hear this didn't work - I would be curious to know what happened - did you get an error? If so, can you add to your question? If the results were incorrect, can you describe further? As for `approx`, `(.I, w)` is the point coordinate for interpolation where `.I` should be the row number,  and `xout = .I` indicating the same row number where interpolation takes place. The `$y` returned is of `(x,y)` coordinates returned as a result of interpolation.

Comment: Hi Ben, I get the error ```Error in approx(.I, ze, .I) : need at least two non-NA values to interpolate```  there are non-NA values. As I am still trying to figure out what caused this Error it is difficult for me to adjust the example above just yet.

Comment: Also - would there be a way to try this out on a subset of your data, instead of all 16M rows? Also (also), if there remains unanswered by later today (2 days after posting) I can start a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) so your question receives more attention. I'd like to see this working for you.

Comment: Your error may come from having all `NA` for a given group of `h`. If all are `NA` then it doesn't have values to interpolate from. Let me look at this further...

Comment: the 16M rows are a tiny subset :) Thanks for the offer but maybe I can make this work coming from your solution.

Comment: See edited answer, this may also help in cases where there are not 2 values available for interpolation.